# How can I get the list-items displayed block?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a drop-up menu. Everything works except the list-items in the drop-up.
Like you can see on this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f671z43v/1/) the list-items in the drop-up (on contact hover) menu are displayed next to each other and not above each other what I want.

I tried this:

```
/*drop-up menu*/

#footer ul li ul.dropup{
  display:none;
}
.dropup li{
  display:block;
}
#footer ul li:hover .dropup{
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:40px;
  border:1px solid #111111;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  border-radius: 7px 7px 0px 0px;
}
```

I also tried to watch tutorials but that didn't help. I normaly don't have this problem when I work with `<ul>` so I don't understand waht cause this problem. I hope somebody can help me.

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/f671z43v/3/ 
You just needed to make the float left more specific by adding chevrons.

```
#footer > ul > li{
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
}
```

by only selecting the direct child the drop-up won't have the float applied.

Comment: That works but why? Isn't the way I select the items not the same?

Comment: by using your original #footer ul li {} this was selecting all the li's within the #footer and applying the float, which is why they're sitting next to one another. By adding a chevron which is selecting the direct child, the style will only be applied to the first set of ul li's.

Comment: Thanks for yoy help and your explaination.

Comment: This will hep explain the sibling and child selectors http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/

Comment: can You tell me why nobody upvoted my Question. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71181/discussion-between-vinc199789-and-aaron).

Answer (score 2):

in your css add a `clear:both` in the dropup li

```
.dropup li{
    display:block;
    clear:both;
    width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you were just tripping over a little selector specificity.

Change:

```
/*drop-up menu*/
#footer ul li ul.dropup{
    display:none;
}
.dropup li{
    display:block;
}
```

To:

```
/*drop-up menu*/
#footer ul li ul.dropup{
    display:none;
}
#footer .dropup li{ /* more specific selector... */
    display:block;
    float: none;
}
```

[**Working Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/f671z43v/10/)

Answer (score 1):

You have to make this addition:

```
#footer ul li ul.dropup li {
    display: block;
    float: none;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f671z43v/8/